# Errors undefined reference Class:: function

Tags: c++, oop

i am quite new to c++ so i have an assignement and trying to experiment a bit before tackling the process of building an AST tree. Trying to input a string expressing (operator and operands ) and splitting it as in the python split but it seems i keep getting either basic class structure problems or compilation problems not sure .

expr.h file

```
#include <string>

class BuildAst
{
public:
    void build(std::string expr);
protected:
    char opera;
    char left_child;
    char right_child;

};
```

expr.cpp file

```
#include "expr.h"
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


void BuildAst::build(std::string expr)
{
   std::string str1, str2;
   std::stringstream s(expr);
   s>>str1>>str1;
   std::cout<<str1<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<str2<<std::endl;
};
```

main.cpp file

```
#include "expr.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
 std::string s;
 std::cout << "Enter the expression\n";
 std::cin >> s;
 BuildAst ast;
 ast.build(s);

 };
```

makefile

```
CFLAGS="--std=c++14"
all: main tests

expr:
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o expr.o expr.cpp

main: expr
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o expr main.cpp expr.o

tests: expr
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o tests testcases.cpp expr.o

clean:
   rm *.o expr tests
```

The input expression i'm trying to use is 3+5 and output should be 3,5
And i keep getting the following errors

[image]

Tried adding to the 3 files (main.cpp/ expr.cpp/expr.h)

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0/1
```

then the error i am getting changed to

[image]

Could you help me please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

okay, turned out i'm not running the files as a project in codeblocks. Problem fixed